# Drupal search-api doesn't index custom body field

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, drupal-search

I've created custom content type, with custom text area field 'field_main_body' (main body field is deleted). The field doesn't show up on search-api index configure page. The search result don't show nodes containing text in this field. I think it's not beeing indexed by search api. I've tried http://ygerasimov.com/add-custom-field-search-api-apachesolr-index sollution, but nothing happened.

Does anyone know how to add this field to search-api index? Or maybe there's another problem here?

Answer (score 0):

Try to re-index until 100% ("admin/config/search/settings" page) or/and run cron. There is no reasons that it is not indexed.

Comment: Thanks for reply. I've done this and nothing happened (search-api index was reindexed couple of times). What's more, I'm using Ubercart products and product body text is indexed and search phrase is found in product body, however in custom content type it's not beeing found (with custom or default body field). I still don'e know what might be wrong.

Comment: Then I don't know, sorry ... Without code it's hard to find out what happens.